# Отсутствует переводы в разделе “Followed posts” на странице Активности

Tags: дефект, локализация, профиль-участника

В разделе “Followed posts” на странице Активности не переведены:

1. заголовок;
2. кнопка сортировки Newest;
3. имя вкладки.